# Change EXIF format in Lightroom Classic

Tags: lightroom, metadata

I noticed Lightroom Classic outputs the Exposure Time in the EXIF data as `0.0025` instead of `1/400`. Is there anyway I can change the format?

Comment: Where you get this? What I see as meta is 1/??? as shutter speed. The same is reported from `exiftool`

Comment: Searching around the web it seems this can differ between cameras. Can you add which camera you are seeing this with? Also, I don't know of any way to change the formatting of this value, but perhaps there's another way to reach your goal. *Why* do you want to show the shutter speed as a fraction?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke maybe just because that's how it is usually expressed, in particular on the camera itself? Without counting 0's, is `0.0025s`, `1/40`, `1/400` or `1/4000`?

Comment: @xenoid I'm not sure I follow...? A shutter speed of `1/400` is equal to 1 second divided by 400, which is an exposure duration of `0.0025` seconds, right? Oh you mean, the "why" is: it's standard and easy to read?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke Yes